# SQL update is not working in asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I wanted to update the cell of the table, but when I did that by writing this code, the table does not get updated and there was no any exceptions or any errors:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("My connection string"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Tablename] SET [notes]=@notes WHERE [ID]=@ID", con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", this.ID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", TextBox1.Text);

        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

When I pass the value of "@notes" by myself it works, but when pass the value of "@notes" TextBox1.Text it is not working. Can someone explain me why?

**Note: TextBox1.TextMode is Multiline**

Comment: What is the value of `TextBox1.Text` exactly? And using `con.Close()` is redundant. [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) will handle that.

Comment: the value of TextBox1.Text is any type of text like "hello world and etc etc"

Comment: Usual reason is there's something wrong with ID. PS con.close is unnecessary.

Comment: Or on occasion the db you think your are connected to isn't the one you are connected to.

Comment: No the ID is correct I've even passed the ID by myself

Comment: isn't it the problem of TextBox mode?

Comment: No errors = id doesn't exist, or no change to notes. That's it. int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery() might tell you something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all of you. That was my fault, I've tried to do what @Tony Hopkinson said in the comment and I get the value of 1(that meant everything is going good). The problem was in Page_Load function, I've changed it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = info;
}
```

To this and everything worked:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = info;
    }  
}
```

Then I've checked the table the value was updated. One more time thanks to all of you...))

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to save the "notes" textBox1 in a string. If it´s multiline use something like String.Join, and then pass the string as the parameter ;) It will works!

BTW.. It´s not neccessary to close the connection with the using SqlConnection, because it will Dispose by itself! ;)